# Why is moment.js date is 50 years ahead?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

Using moment to format a date retrieved from a firestore timestamp. However the date is off by at least a day, and at most, a few months. and the year is off by 50 no matter what.

Here is the firestore timestamp

[image]

EDIT: Here is whats logged from `lastMsg.seconds`:
`1581372232`

I retrieve the time in seconds in a FlatList's renderItem:

```
 renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <Components.InboxItem
                title={item.withName}
                subtitle={item.lastMsg.seconds}
                img={item.withImg}
            />
        );
```

And finally inside the component I use moment like so:

```
const date = moment()
  .utc()
  .startOf('year')
  .seconds(props.subtitle)
  .format('MMMM DD YYYY');
```

While ive tried multiple format configurations, the one that gets it closest to accurate is with `.startOf("year")`. Even then, date is being displayed as "February 09, 2070". If `.startOf()` is changed to "month", "day", or "hour", the date gets changed to sometime in march. How can this be fixed to display the date as in firestore?

Comment: can you add the actual data you retrieve inside your js code from firestore beside the screenshot of timestamp from console?

Comment: edited with time in seconds

Comment: The problem is `moment().utc().startOf('year')` gives you 2020/01/01, and `.seconds(...)` _adds_ that amount to the date. The number of years between unix epoch (1970/01/01) and 2020 is 50, so you're getting ~50 years added to 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp we can either get JS `Date` object or use the `toMillis` method to get milliseconds.

Now the simple moment.js api for converting timestamp to moment object is given here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

`moment(Number);`

Now you can apply format on the moment object like below:

`moment(Number).format(String);`

Your issue with wrong date is may be due to the use of `utc` and `seconds` together and not passing timestamp to `moment()`

Comment: how do I use toMillis() in a firestore read with react-native-firebase? I'm writing the `lastMsg` with `firebase.firestoreFieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: item.lastMsg should be firestore timestamp object and you can call the function on that. I assume the react-native-firebase lib should do the same.

Comment: https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/firestore/reference/timestamp#toMillis

Comment: ah initially when I tried `doc.get('time').toMillis()` it didnt work. second attempt it works

Answer (score 1):

Use [`moment.unix()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/):

```js
const props = {
  subtitle: 1581372232
};

const date = moment
  .unix(props.subtitle)
  .format('MMMM DD YYYY');

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

because [`item.lastMsg.seconds`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#seconds) is

> The number of seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: `moment.unix(props.subtitle)` gives me `1581375138`...then what? it doesn't work with any other moment functions

Comment: @Jim I assumed the `.format()` was implied. `.unix()` returns an instance of moment, not a string.